# How can I make a gradient top border with a radius?

Tags: css, border, gradient, linear-gradients

I've been trying to make a gradient top border for a box with a radius. The gradient border should only be at the top of the box, and it needs to have the same radius (5px) as the rest of the box. The end result should look like this:

[image: How the box with the gradient top border should look]

My current code:

```css
.card {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 1%;
  background-color: #252a41;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 3% 0;
}

.instagram {
  border-top: 3px solid rgb(243, 242, 241);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fdc468, #ffa263, #ff806c, #f9607f, #df4996) 1 / 3px 0px 0px 0px / 0px 0px 0px 0px round;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="card instagram">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="images/icon-instagram.svg" alt="instagram icon" />
    <span class="small-text username">@realnathanf</span>
  </div>
  <h1 class="followers-count">11k</h1>
  <p class="small-text followers">FOLLOWERS</p>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="images/icon-up.svg" alt="icon up" />
    <span class="change change-up">1099 Today</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Apparently the `border-image` property isn't compatible with border radius, so I have to make a before/after pseudo-element. However I couldn't figure out how to make one for the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with only background:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:5px;
  background:
     linear-gradient(to right, #fdc468, #ffa263, #ff806c, #f9607f, #df4996) top/100% 5px no-repeat,
     #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```